# Confused about this theorem in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

this theorem is from lecture notes

> $\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$ are linearly dependent iff $X_3$ span $\{X_1,X_2\}$.

I think it is wrong because we can show $X_1$ and $X_2$ is also can be expressed as a linear combination of the other vectors

Am I right? Or is there something wrong with my conclusion?

Comment: Are you claiming that a linear combination of vectors is not a vector? What is it then?

Comment: If that's a linearly dependent set, then one of those three vectors is a linear combination of the others. WLOG, say the third is a linear combination of the other two, i.e., in their span.

Comment: If $X_1=X_2=0\ne X_3$ then $\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$ is a linearly dependent set (because $1\cdot X_1+1\cdot X_2+0\cdot X_3=0$) but $X_3$ is not in the span of $\{X_1,X_2\}.$

Comment: What does "$X_3$ span $\{X_1,X_2\}$" even _mean_?????

Comment: Linear dependence means there must exist $a,b,c$ with $aX_1+bX_2+cX_3=0$. How does this relate to the span?

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand your reasoning, but the theorem you mention is wrong. Take for example $\mathbb R^2$, then $\{(1, 0), (2,0), (0, 1)\}$ are linearly dependent, but $(0,1)\notin span\{(1, 0), (2, 0)\}=span\{(1, 0)\}$.

Comment: @just_a_math_lover Adding to the answer: Any list of vectors in a finite dimensional vector space whose length is longer than the basis of that vector space would be linearly dependent. As the length of a linearly independent list is less than or equal to the length of a basis.

Comment: Hi Brifa, thank you for your time, but I really want to delete this post because I think it is a very bad one but I can't because of your answer, so sorry I am asking this but can you delete your answer so I can delete my post because I don't want this question to stuck in my account Please.